# Compile: Putting integers into a list

Tags: compile

The first part below is already answered, but I've got another question which I think is closely related to this one, so I edited my question.

**First part:**
I started compiling in Mathematica a few weeks ago.
In the code below, I want to put the integer value 0 into the list "Pre". If I "Print" the list, it will look like {0,0,....,0}. But the output of the code is {0.,0.,0.,....,0.}.
So, my question is, how can I manage it, that the output looks like the "Print", i.e. I want the list to have integer values and not real numbers.

```
In[1]:= CInit = Compile[{{v0, _Integer, 0}, {s0, _Integer, 0}},
          Module[{s = s0, v = v0, d, Pre},
          d = Table[$MaxMachineNumber, {v}];
          Pre = Table[0, {v}];
          Print[Pre];
          d[[s]] = 0.;
          {d, Pre}
          ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
        CInit[5, 1]

 During evaluation of In[1]:= {0,0,0,0,0}

 Out[2]= {{0., 1.79769*10^308, 1.79769*10^308, 1.79769*10^308, 
         1.79769*10^308}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
```

**Second part:**

If I have an empty list and I want to put Integers into it, how can I let Mathematica know that it is a list of Integers and not Reals? I tried to manage this with the third argument in Compile, but that didn't work. For example:

```
In[22]:= CTest = Compile[{{s, _Integer}}, Module[{Perm = {s}},
         Perm = {};
         Append[Perm, 1]
         ], {{Perm, _Integer, 1}}, CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

> Compile::cset: Variable Perm of type {_Integer,1} encountered in assignment of type >{_Real,1}. >>
>
> Compile::cset: Variable Perm of type {_Integer,1} encountered in assignment of type >{_Real,1}. >>

I can avoid this error by doing this rather unnecessary thing below:

```
In[25]:= CTest = Compile[{{s, _Integer}}, Module[{Perm = {s}},
         Perm = Delete[Perm, 1];
         Append[Perm, 1]
         ], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

So, is there another way to tell Mathematica that Perm is a list of Integers without doing it like in the last example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `Compile`, you can't return a list where sublists are of different type, so integers are converted into reals. This is one of the limitations of `Compile`. To some extent, you can alleviate this by some kind of post-processing of the result, e.g. `MapAt[Round, CInit[5, 1], 2]`.

Comment: In short: since `$MaxMachineNumber` is not an integer, a conversion of your list to have entirely real entries is performed. To compare, try replacing `$MaxMachineNumber` with some other integer.

Comment: It seems when the compiled function returns an array it is always made homogeneous. One float and the whole thing is cast as float.  Makes sense, but really how hard would it be for the good folks at wolfram to just say that in the docs..?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Leonid Shifrin. The "MapAt"-function helped me a lot.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding why you did `d[[s]] = 0.;` instead of `d[[s]] = 0;` in your first snippet.

Comment: Well, the first part of my question is a little time ago and as I mentioned, I could solve this problem. But I also asked myself today why I made it that way, but I think I also tried it with d[[s]]=0 and I got the problem described in the question. I hope somebody can help me with the second part.

Comment: You can use `Perm = Most@{0}` to create an empty list of integer type.

Comment: @SimonWoods I think that's worth making into an answer, both because this hasn't got an answer yet, and also because it's sufficiently obscure that people may not be inclined to think of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the second part of the question, you can use `Most@{0}` to create an empty list of integer type:

```
CTest = Compile[{{s, _Integer}},
  Module[{Perm = Most@{0}}, Append[Perm, 1]],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```